# HtmlUnit processing whitespace

Tags: htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit to do some processing of an Html page.  My problem is that it does not seem to be correctly maintaining whitespace.

The original html looks like:

```
<div><cite>www.<b>example</b>.com</cite>
```

Which renders as:

www.**example**.com

After using html unit to do some parsing on other parts of the dom, I print the html back out using getXml().  Doing so causes the html to be pretty printed:

```
  <div>
    <cite>
      www.
      <b>
        example
      </b>
      .com
     </cite>
```

This ends up rendering as:

www. **example** .com

Note the extra space before and after example.

I tried just trimming the whitespace from resulting pretty-printed dom, but then you lose spaces in places where you actually want them.

Stepping through the generated dom, it appears that HtmlUnit trims all of the DomText nodes when it creates them, so the space information is lost.

Is there any way I can configure HtmlUnit to track this information?  Or some alternative that better maintains the original html?  I just need to be able to extra portions of the html via XPath.

Comment: Does the pretty-printing use spaces or tabs?  If tabs, couldn't you replace all newlines and tabs in the output markup, while leaving spaces alone?

Comment: Thats a good thought. It looks like the spaces are not maintained at all though, its all just aligned according to the indentations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should return the original html:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.yourpage.com");
String originalHtml = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I need an altered version of the page, so I need to get it from the constructed page, not the original web response.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript gets the html without the extra whitespace:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);
client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);

String html = htmlPage.executeJavaScript("document.body.parentNode.outerHTML")
    .getJavaScriptResult()
    .toString();
```